# Initialization of plist file

Tags: objective-c, plist

in my app I've a plist file of configuration, each viewController, in viewDidLoad load data from it and write.

The problem is: how can I create this plist file in Documents folder on first startup of application? I think to do this in viewDidLoad of first ViewController of the app, but maybe is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it in the `UIApplication` delegate message `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`? In there, check to see if the file exists in the Documents directory. If it doesn't, create it.

Comment: But is not a heavy operation? in my case plist have only 3-4 elemeents...but if i have had a big file is always this better solution? (sorry bad english)